# Cant find hard drive in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

So my computer already has Windows installed on a 1 TB hard drive and just purchased a 120 GB SSD that I believe is correctly installed.  Last night I set the BIOS to automatically start to the SSD and I chose the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.  I intended for Ubuntu to solely be on the SSD and Windows to only be on the hard drive.  I am fairly certain that Ubuntu was properly installed on the SSD, however, for whatever reason I can't find it when I am using Ubuntu, I can only find the hard drive.  How do I find this SSD where Ubuntu is supposed to be installed?

images from gparted:

[image: gparted1]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ran gparted and from what I can tell, it appears that Ubuntu is installed on /dev/sdb.  I included an imgur album of both screenshots of /dev/sda and /dev/sdb and I would appreciate your help.  Thank you. http://imgur.com/a/DOaz9

Comment: According to your pictures, you are using your SSD and it's mounted at / (the root of your directory tree) 'nix systems don't use drive letters like Windows does. Everything is mounted to the same directory tree. `cat /etc/mtab` will show you what is currently mounted (not all of these are storage devices) `cat /etc/fstab` will show you what drives are supposed to be mounted at boot time and where. You can enter the above commands from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Disks (14.04) or disk Utility (12.04) On your system you will see something very similar to this:

[image: DiskUtility]

Here you will see all your drives. Select one and you'll see details regarding how they are partitioned and where they are mounted (if they are). You can see above that the first partition of my SSD is mounted at / (yours looks to be the same).

You can see all your drives and partitions with the command `sudo fdisk -l` everything that's currently mounted to the tree with `cat /etc/mtab` and all the filesystems that are configured to mount at boot with `cat /etc/fstab`. If you manually mount or unmount a drive /etc/mtab will be updated but /etc/fstab will not be. /etc/fstab can be edited to add "permanent" mounting of a filesystem at boot time.

In short you have done everything right and have no problem. To see how much space you have available  on your mounted drive(s) issue the command `df -h` in the terminal. You'll get a response similar to this:

`tvbox@tvbox-G31M-ES2L:~$ df -h`

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`

`/dev/sdb1        58G   11G   45G  20% /`

`udev            995M  4.0K  995M   1% /dev`

`tmpfs           201M  832K  200M   1% /run`

`none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock`

`none           1002M  920K 1001M   1% /run/shm`

`/dev/sda3       867G  387G  436G  48% /home`

`/dev/sdc1       3.7G  7.5M  3.5G   1% /media/0c3616b2-8c41-4e6d-8a1e-4dd192923088`

`/dev/sr0        6.2G  6.2G     0 100% /media/08294`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing well, the disk/partition with Ubuntu itself normally is not shown in the Nautilus as, for example, the Windows partitions are shown. Instead you can see it in `gparted` as at your picture,

[image]

or, for example, in:

`mount -l`

which makes me thing you will find there this string:

`/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)`

Comment: Don't you mean `mount` ?

Comment: @ElderGeek yes, `mount -l` I said.